# Variable BehaviorSubject inside subscribe get undefined

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I create variable entities$ it is BehaviorSubject but inside subscribe this variable get undefined, if anybody know what is the problem I will be thankth[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4ygh.png)

Comment: Is the variable ``entities$``` really neded? If not, it usually is best to just return an Observable of the HTTP response value

Answer (score 0):

for your problem you must put your code inside subscribe like this:

```
this.http.get().subscribe(items=>{
  this.items=items;
  this.entities$.next(items);
})
```

but actually you don't need items variable inside the service because your entites$ is BehaviorSubject and you can get it's value by calling getValue().
and best practice of your code like this:

```
this.entites$=this.http.get();
```

and subscribe entities$ in the component that it needs its value.